# Variational Operator in mathematica

Tags: functions

I'm trying to do the following variational operation in Mathmatica and VariationalD command doesn't give me the correct answer. Is there any other command that I am unaware of ?
$\delta (y'' * y) = \delta y'' * y + \delta y * y''$

Answer (score 3):

```
D[y'' y /. y -> y + s δy, s] /. s -> 0
```

> δy y^′′ + y δy^′′